# array of objects: want to access one property but I get "Trying to get property of non-object in ..."

Tags: arrays, object, pdo, php

From my database I get only one result. Nevertheless I get an array returned because of this code

```
while($obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $result[] = $obj;
}
```

The returned array has only one element (object) at the index 0. From this object I want access a property.

My code looks like:

`return $result[0]->_id;`

I get the notice

> Trying to get property of non-object in ...

Here are my dumps:

`var_dump`

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (13) { ["_id"]=> string(8) "43001613" ["another-property"]=> string(5) "20608" } }
```

`print_r`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 43001613
            [another-property] => 20608
        )

)
```

It is for sure only a small error but I can't figure it out now.

**Edit:**
Here is the full function:

```
public function getOrtIDForPLZ($plz){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM verortung WHERE plz = :plz LIMIT 1;";
    $result = $this->ExecuteQuery($sql, array("plz"=>$plz));

    var_dump($result);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';

    return $result[0]->_id;
}
```

Output:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#32 (13) { ["_id"]=> string(8) "43006637" ["gemeindekennziffer"]=> string(5) "32330" ["gemeindename"]=> string(13) "Theresienfeld" ["ortsname"]=> string(13) "Theresienfeld" ["plz"]=> string(4) "2604" ["bezirk"]=> string(21) "Wiener Neustadt -Land" ["bundesland"]=> string(17) "Niederösterreich" ["lat"]=> string(11) "47.85000000" ["lon"]=> string(11) "16.23333330" ["einwohner_2001"]=> string(4) "2490" ["kfz-kennzeichen"]=> string(2) "WB" ["fläche_km2"]=> string(5) "11.44" ["seehöhe"]=> string(3) "282" } }

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 43006637
            [gemeindekennziffer] => 32330
            [gemeindename] => Theresienfeld
            [ortsname] => Theresienfeld
            [plz] => 2604
            [bezirk] => Wiener Neustadt -Land
            [bundesland] => Niederösterreich
            [lat] => 47.85000000
            [lon] => 16.23333330
            [einwohner_2001] => 2490
            [kfz-kennzeichen] => WB
            [fläche_km2] => 11.44
            [seehöhe] => 282
        )

)

NULL
```

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/www/home/includes/class.DatabaseQuery.php on line 4507

Comment: Not an answer to your question: To achieve what you want you could just put `return $obj->_id;` in the loop instead of storing it.

Comment: @AndréHoffmann: You assume too much about that specific loop.

Comment: @AndréHoffmann: Which loop? The `while` statement is used for returning results from the database. The important line is `return $result[0]->_id;` which is not in a loop.

Comment: @testing: This doesn't appear to be possible. It could be a "stupid moment" error -- triple check the variable names, scopes, etc.

Comment: Are you dumping `$result` in the same scope as your suspicious `return $result[0]->_id`?

Comment: I don't believe you. Show full code with print_r.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Here you go. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably calling this method multiple times. In the first call everything is all right, but in the next one...

See that `NULL`? Surely you cannot get a property of `NULL`.

If that's not the case, then line 4507 points to somewhere else.

Comment: Your 100% right. I called it a second time but the second time the parameter `plz` was empty.